# Meteor loading order clarification

Tags: meteor

I just need some clarification on Meteor's default loading order.

I placed the following code

```
function isValid(str) {
  return !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
}
```

inside `/lib/utils.js`

and tried calling it from `/client/views/userprofile.js`

```
  if (isValid(newUsername)) {
    Meteor.call('editUsername', newUsername);
  }
```

However, it says `isValid` is undefined. What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isValid` is not a global function. Use `isValid = function(){ [...] }` instead of `function isValid(){ [...] }` to make it global.

Comment: Because `function x() {}` is the same as `var x = function(){}`, and `var` makes it file scoped. See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/namespacing